# C#: How to Marshal VariantBool to managed boolean?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, wrapper, finereader

I am currently working on a Wrapper Class for a C++ Library in C# (dotnet core 3.1 on debian linux) and struggling with DllImport the following method (taken from the libs documentation):

```
HRESULT __stdcall InitializeEngine(
    BSTR CustomerProjectID,
    BSTR LicensePath,
    BSTR LicensePassword,
    BSTR FREngineDataFolder,
    BSTR FREngineTempFolder,
    VARIANT_BOOL IsSharedCPUCoresMode,
    IEngine** Engine);
```

**Update: Looking further in the header files, the COM Types are typedefs. Therefore the actual signature looks something like this:**

```
int __stdcall InitializeEngine(
        wchar_t* CustomerProjectID,
        wchar_t* LicensePath,
        wchar_t* LicensePassword,
        wchar_t* FREngineDataFolder,
        wchar_t* FREngineTempFolder,
        short IsSharedCPUCoresMode,
        IEngine** Engine);
```

My Import currently looks like this:

```
[DllImport("FREngine", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]        
extern static int InitializeEngine(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string customerProjectID, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string licensePath, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string licensePassword, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string frEngineDataFolder, 
        short isSharedCPUCoresMode,
        ref IntPtr engine);
```

But this does not work. Is this the correct translation of the method signature?

Comment: `VARIANT*` and `BSTR` are Windows COM classes, and there is no COM in Linux. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: This doesn't get put the test very often on the Linuxes.  The parameter is *short* at runtime, 0 = false, -1 = true.  I'm guessing that it actually complains about the last parameter, it must be `out IntPtr` to make [Out] work.  Hmm, off by one bug....

Comment: @Blindy As i mentioned, the signature is taken from the official documentation, the c++ header files contain the same definition. This Library is available on Windows, Linux and OSX. Maybe thats the reason for using these types.

Comment: Listen to Hans, he knows what he’s talking about!